# Save the order of the rearranged cells in a table view

Tags: uitableview

I have an application which can rearrange the order of the UITableViewCells and can delete the cells However, I needa way to save the order of the rearranged and deleted table view cells. I am using an nsmutablearray

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
if (!maTheData) {
maTheData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]     initWithObjects:@"Bus", @"Truck", @"Car",nil];


}
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:  (UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView   numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [maTheData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath           *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView   dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"tvcItems"];
UILabel *lblName = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
[lblName setText:[maTheData objectAtIndex:   [indexPath row]]];
return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView   commitEditingStyle:         (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle      forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
// Delete the row from the data source
[maTheData removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
// Delete row using the cool literal version of [NSArray     arrayWithObject:indexPath]
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]       withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
else if (editingStyle ==  UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
// Insert something into the array, and you can just    add a populated NSIndexPath of   data or simplr reload    data
[maTheData addObject:@"I'm a new item!"];
[tableView reloadData];
}
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath   toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
 {
NSString *mover = [maTheData objectAtIndex: [fromIndexPath row]];
[maTheData removeObjectAtIndex:[fromIndexPath    row]];
[maTheData insertObject:mover atIndex:[toIndexPath row]];

[tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];

}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
return YES;
}



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
[tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
 }
```

Comment: So what exactly does not work with the code you show? Do you have a crash? The only problem I see is that you never create a cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. After you dequeue a cell from the table view you should say `if (!cell) { cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] init...] autorelease]; }`

Comment: I need to save the order of the cells. I dont know how to do that. Everything is running fine.

Comment: I don't think I understand. The table view cells are a visual representation of your data in `maTheData`. When a new cell is inserted, or an existing cell is deleted or moved, you nicely update `maTheData` to reflect the change in the GUI. The order of your cells is therefore reflected by the order of the elements in `maTheData`. So what else do you want?

Comment: I want the table view to reflect the changes I made when the app opens up again. So, I want to save the order of the cells.

Answer (score -2):

To preserve data across application relaunch you have to serialize the content of `maTheData` into `NSData`, then write the content of `NSData` to disk either via `NSUserDefaults`, or to a file of your own choosing. In the latter case you must also decide in which folder you want to place that file - I would suggest something like the Application Support folder, or at any rate, *not* the Documents folder.

I know this is not a copy&paste solution, but it should get you started on your further research. Just read the Apple docs and google, there are plenty of resources on the net that explain how to do this in detail.